# Getting depth map from disparity map

Tags: opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi3, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

From my understanding, we can use the following formula to obtain the real distance from depth map. 
The focal length of a pi camera in terms of pixel is 2571.4, while the distance betweeen my two cameras is 0.065m. so using this formula based on the triangulation method,

Distance = (focal length * distance between 2 camera)/disparity map.

I also generated a disparity map with the following code:

```
stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=48, blockSize=25)
disparity = steeo.compute(rectified_pair[0], rectified_pair[1])
norm_image = cv2.normalize(disparity, None, alpha = 0, beta =1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv.CV_32F)

f = 2571.4 
b = 0.065
distance = (b*f)/disparity
cv2.imshow(norm_image)
```

I realize my 'disparity' image range starts from -16.
I am getting negative values for both set of codes and I am unsure if this is a correct method to calculate distance. Also, I have calibrated my cameras.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should read the values of focal length and baseline from the calibration file and not hardcode it. If it is done properly, the way I used to calculate depth is going pixel by pixel. So I would apply the same formula pixel by pixel like this :

depthmap.at(i,j) = (b*f) / disparitymap.at(i,j).

You can maybe try this. Mostly there would be any negative values in the disparity map that is return by StereoBM compute. So there might a problem only after that process.

Answer (score 0):

If you calibrated and rectified cameras by yourself, openCV provides a function for disparity-to-depth transform
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1bc1152bd57d63bc524204f21fde6e02

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32925919)